# best python-driven forecasting model using historical goal periods?

Tags: python, machine-learning, integer, forecasting

I'm eager to hear opinions on relevant forecasting/ML models which best rely on historical goal periods. That is, goal periods which have a fixed budget and "performance" goal at either a weekly or monthly cadence.

My understanding is that something like the ARIMA model would work, or with deep learning the LSTM, but without experience with forecasting, it's a shot in the dark on my end.

My end aim is to be able to feed the model unseen test dat (say a weekly goal period) where I can input spend and performance from the third of seven days, and output the percentage probability that budget is met and performance goal is met too.

For additional context, the performance metric would be a basic set of mixed integer values.

Comment: I would start with multiple linear regression.

Comment: For data that contain periodicities ARIMA models are a good start. If you are new to the those there are many resources on youtube you could check out. A second step could be experimenting with a Kalman filter to track some selected ARIMA model parameters.

Comment: I suggest starting with methods that do not involve ML, at the very least to create a benchmark to compare ML models to later on.